# Can cylindrical co-ordinates be used in this problem?

Tags: integration, volume

Find the volume using triple integrals of the region bounded by

$z=x^2+9y^2$ and $z=18-x^2-9y^2$

In cartesian co-ordinates, the get the following limit -

$$\int_{y=-1}^1\int_{x=-\sqrt{9-9y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-9y^2}}\int_{z=x^2+9y^2}^{18-x^2-9y^2}dxdydz$$

Is this correct ?  Can this type of integral be converted into cylindrical co-ordinates for easy evaluation ?

Comment: Yes. You can do it safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but elliptical cylindrical coordinates.  That is, $\rho^2=x^2+9 y^2$.  The Jacobian of the transformation is thus $\rho/3$.  The integral is then

$$V = \frac13 \int_0^{2 \pi} d\phi \, \int_0^3 d\rho \, \rho \, \int_{\rho^2}^{18-\rho^2} dz $$

It is straightforward to show that $V = 27 \pi$.

Comment: How do we define \rho ? What are the substitutions we use ?

Comment: @AmanMittal: I defined $\rho$ in my post.  We are subbing $x=\rho \cos{\phi}$, $y = (1/3) \rho \sin{\phi}$.

Comment: yeah, thats what i was looking for. does this kind of substitution work generally in cases of ellipse ?

Comment: ron, can you please also look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521259/volume-using-triple-integrals